# Creating an interface by extracting types from an interface

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```js
interface FooBar {
    foo: string;
    bar: number; 
}
```

Is there a way to, dynamically, creates a type that accepts 'foo' or 'bar'?

like:

```js
const update = (obj: FooBar, key: string, value: string | number) => {
   ...
}
```

In this case, instead of `string | number`, I would like to extract the values from `FooBar` so I don't have to update two places at once

Any ideas? Thanks so far

Comment: `keyof Foobar` yields the the union type `'foo' | 'bar'`.

Comment: Since you asked how to get the union of the values, the answer is type FooBarValues = FooBar[keyof FooBar]. But that’s not what you actually want to use here.  You want to follow @ccarton’s answer which enforces that the value is the correct type for the provided key, not just the type for any key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the key type a generic parameter and then index the interface:

```
function update<K extends keyof FooBar> (obj: FooBar, key: K, value: FooBar[K]) {
  obj[key] = value
}

update(obj, 'bar', 10) // OK
update(obj, 'foo', 'x') // OK

update(obj, 'foo', 10) // Error
// --------------> ~~ 
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Comment: Thanks, man... this is exactly what I'm looking for